# How to map static inner classes in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb

Initially, I have Java class generated using XJC (JAXB utility). How to arrange the annotation to save the entity of ClaimType?  ClaimType and Reason relate as  OneToMany.

```
package com.belkam.res.domain;

import com.belkam.utils.DateUtils;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;


public class ClaimType {
    protected long claimId;
    protected long rsnPart;
    protected ClaimType.ReasonList resasonList;
    //Defalut constructor and getters &setters
    public static class ReasonList {
        protected List<ClaimType.ReasonList.Reason> reason;
        public List<ClaimType.ReasonList.Reason> getReason() {
            if (reason == null) {
                reason = new ArrayList<ClaimType.ReasonList.Reason>();
            }
            return this.reason;
        }
        public static class Reason {
            protected long reasonId;
            protected int reasonType;
            protected String reasonNum;
            @Transient
            protected XMLGregorianCalendar reasonDate;
            protected String lineNum;
            protected String resBsNum;
            //Defalut constructor and getters &setters
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add usual mappings? What did not work?

Comment: Yes of course.
I add Entity annotation over  the classes ClaimType and Reason
Id And GeneratedValue over the properties and claimId reasonId

But I do not know where to place the annotation 
OneToMany
JoinColumn (Name = "claimId")

Comment: If I mark OneToMany JoinColumn (Name = "claimId") on public ReasonList getResasonList()  like here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html , I get exception Could not determine type for: com.belkam.res.domain.ClaimType$ReasonList, at table: claim_type, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(resason_list)]

Comment: @SergeyTarabara, did you succeed in getting this to work?  If so, how? I'm beset by exactly the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this exception appears in some situations when you use mixed style for annotations (both fields and getters). You should always use one approach for a single entity: either annotate fields or getters.

Also, it may help to explicitly specify the target entity, maybe Hibernate is confused with the inner class:

```
@OneToMany(... targetEntity = ClaimType.ReasonList.class)
```

Generaly, Hibernate supports static inner classes to be entities. I am not sure for JPA though, maybe there is some mismatch between Hibernate and JPA here (although I would assume that Hibernate as a superset of JPA would still allow this even with JPA annotations).

In case that this is a JPA specification issue, you could try to define mappings in hbm files for these entities. The other benefit of this would be that you will not loose mappings when you regenerate classes with JAXB utilities.

Comment: I do not understand why need  targetEntity in this case. Now I have exception Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a OneToMany, ManyToMany or CollectionOfElements: com.belkam.res.domain.ClaimType.resasonList in the code:

Comment: <!-- language: lang-java -->
`@Entity
public class ClaimType {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 protected long claimId;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "claimtype", targetEntity = ClaimType.ReasonList.class)
 @JoinColumn(name = "claimId")
 protected ClaimType.ReasonList resasonList;
  //getters & setters
  public static class ReasonList {
  protected List<Reason> reason;
  // public List<Reason> getReason()
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "Reason")
   public static class Reason {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected long reasonId;
    //getters & setters
  }
 }
}`

Comment: This should be a `ToOne` association (since `ReasonList` is not a collection itself, but contains a collection). You know better whether it is `OneToOne`, or `ManyToOne`, I am not familiar with your model.